# WebBrowser Controls Script error

Tags: javascript, html, winforms, bots

I am making a bot which visits to a specific url, give the input in form and submit it by clicking to submit button...

Let me explain you my situation. When I start my bot, firstly it visits the URL, after web page is loaded, I have to check one radio button manually there and after this I press submit button (windows form control button to fill all fields of web page and submit it also by using invoke click method) to submit form.

I am using Web browser control (coding in C#.NET windows form) and the problem is when I click on a radio button, a pop up window pops up with the heading "Script Error" and says [image]

Below is the tag of radio button (on which error pops up) which I copied by using IE development tool.

```
<input name="array(BlastDatabaseType)" onchange="changeQuestion(); changeAlgorithms();"
type="radio" value="Proteins"/>
```

This error don't occur on normal web browser.
I want to solve this error not to hide.

Comment: I guess you want to submit the page by programmatically clicking on submit button ,but the JavaScript error is causing problems ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have understood from your question that you need to fix the javascript error which is generated due to Web browser Control,

**There are two basic solutions,**

**1)** Force the Web Browser control to emulate the latest IE browser.
You need to make a registry change for this ,and you will be able to use the IE browser installed on the PC.

*Adapted from [Mikel Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control#4613025)*
You can use a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >` inside the HTML page.

But its better to add a registry entry to: `(goto > start > run > type 'regedit' enter)`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER) > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Internet Explorer >
Main > FeatureControl > FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION > contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00009000`

use `10000 (0x02710)` for Internet Explorer 10

**2)** Use the GeckoFX wrapper ,it wraps the Gecko engine,
*Download* the [GeckoFX wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)
*Download* the [XulRunner](http://mirrors.directorymix.com/mozilla/xulrunner/releases/1.9.1.2/runtimes/xulrunner-1.9.1.2.en-US.win32.zip)

First extract the GeckoFX and read the readme.txt file.

Add reference of the Gecko.dll in you toolbar ,and then drag and drop the control on your Form.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //you need to extract the Xulrunner in the soultion directory
        //  (preferable) b/c wrapper relies on these dlls.
        Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\Xulrunner");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://tritrypdb.org/tritrypdb/"); 
    }
```

**Other useful Links:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation
[Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are two different versions of FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. There is one for 64-bit apps and one for 32-bit apps. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42864875/167920

Answer (score 0):

IE handles differently the onchange event. IE only fires the onchange event when the element loses focus.

If I understood your question correctly, You might want to use onkeypress event instead.

Comment: Accept my apology please. please consider my question again.